# Custom action url error while deploy: Error occurred in deployment step

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have some strange error. In sharepoint 2010 I have something like:

```
        <UrlAction Url="javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('{SiteUrl}/Style Library/AdminPage/AdminPage.aspx?itemid={ItemId}&#38;listid={ListId}');" />
```

and it workes

but in sharepoint 2013 i have error while deploy

> Error 1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': There were errors when validating the App Package.

app is in autohosted mode. I dont know what to do, i tried any js in urlaction it doesn't want to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i found out.

If you add JavaScript code in the CommandAction, your app will not get deployed in SharePoint. It will result in the following error message (ULS logs) - Unexpected exception: There were errors when validating the App package: There were errors when validating the App Package. Other warnings / errors associated with this exception:  Custom action urls must start with "http:", "https:", "~appWebUrl" or "~remoteAppUrl". The solutions is new atribute like in customactions:

```
            HostWebDialog="TRUE"
            HostWebDialogHeight="420"
            HostWebDialogWidth="510"
```

i think it can help someone

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220046.aspx) that is not possible:

> CustomAction cannot contain JavaScript: Any UrlActions or
>   CommandActions must be a URL to navigate to. The URL can be
>   parameterized with normal custom actions tokens in addition to the
>   app-specific tokens.

Using HostWebDialog seem to be the preferred approach for this scenario. You might also consider passing an additional parameter for your page in the App Web, so it will identify it was opened from CustomAction.